Why does a requests.get(...) call hang
The following simple python script that uses requests.get to execute a GET request does not return on my computer:
import requests
print(requests.get('https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/1894790125'))

However, I am able to get an "instant" response with the same url using curl.
Why is this?
Specifying a common user agent
Specifying a common user agent does not change anything:
import requests

print(requests.get(
   'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/1894790125',
    headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' }
))

tcpdump
When trying to trace the connection with
 sudo tcpdump -v -i eno1 'host api.openstreetmap.org'

I get the following output
tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:17:22.463843 IP6 (flowlabel 0x69a8c, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:dddd:cccc:bbbb.aaaa4 > spike-06.openstreetmap.org.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xdb71 (incorrect -> 0xb5a5), seq 3910911789, win 64800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1030348905 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:17:23.482673 IP6 (flowlabel 0xd077e, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:dddd:cccc:bbbb.aaaa4 > spike-06.openstreetmap.org.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xdb71 (incorrect -> 0xb1aa), seq 3910911789, win 64800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1030349924 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:17:25.494643 IP6 (flowlabel 0x3cc5c, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:dddd:cccc:bbbb.aaaa4 > spike-06.openstreetmap.org.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xdb71 (incorrect -> 0xa9ce), seq 3910911789, win 64800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1030351936 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:17:29.687440 IP6 (flowlabel 0x7665b, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:dddd:cccc:bbbb.aaaa4 > spike-06.openstreetmap.org.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xdb71 (incorrect -> 0x996e), seq 3910911789, win 64800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1030356128 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:17:37.878687 IP6 (flowlabel 0xd5551, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:dddd:cccc:bbbb.aaaa4 > spike-06.openstreetmap.org.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xdb71 (incorrect -> 0x796e), seq 3910911789, win 64800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1030364320 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:17:54.010694 IP6 (flowlabel 0xbf2f2, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:dddd:cccc:bbbb.aaaa4 > spike-06.openstreetmap.org.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xdb71 (incorrect -> 0x3a6a), seq 3910911789, win 64800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1030380452 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
^C
6 packets captured
28 packets received by filter
3 packets dropped by kernel

Unfortunately, I am quite inexperienced interpreting such output, and I am not sure if the incorrect part in the output is an indication of what's going on.
Working in WSL
When executed in WSL on the same hardware, the request runs fine and the script prints <Response [200]>.

Running this I get <Response [200]>. Try to set different User-Agent header.

I can't think of any reason why the OSM API would check user agents. It's intended to be used from server applications, not browsers.

Use a packet capture tool to see where it's hanging.

OSM API has rate limiting and abuse filters in place, which you're probably hitting here. Also note that the OSM API is strictly for map editing purposes only, not for some random server applications doing look ups. There are alternatives available for read-only use cases (such as Overpass API).

I would assume that in case of hitting a rate limit, I'd receive a HTTP status 429 - but this is not the case, I don't even get a response at all. Besides, this request hung already the first time - and I can request from this endpoint from the browser or with WSL.

Can you please check if the alternatives you've mentioned are using IPv4 vs. IPv6? From your tcpdump snippet it seems you're experiencing issues with IPv6. If possible, maybe try IPv4 instead. OSM operations might be able to give you more specific advise on https://github.com/openstreetmap/operations/issues
